# Unknown attribute class warning with FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, settings, preferencefragment

I have a `SettingsFragment` class that hosts a `PreferenceFragment` for the app settings.

In layout, I used `FragmentContainerView` which points to that `PreferenceFragment` class with the `class` attribute.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    class="xxxxxx.fragments.SettingsFragment$PreferenceFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Backing to normal `fragment` instead of `FragmentContainerView` the warning is gone, so it turns out that it's related to `FragmentContainerView`.

How can I get rid of this warning while using `FragmentContainerView`?

Comment: It should be  android:name="xxxxxx.fragments.SettingsFragment$PreferenceFragment"
as per FragmentContainerView documentation.

Comment: Technically, `FragmentContainerView` supports both `class` and `android:name`. Studio just doesn't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `android:name="xxxxxx.fragments.SettingsFragment$PreferenceFragment"` as per `FragmentContainerView` documentation.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="xxxxxx.fragments.SettingsFragment$PreferenceFragment"
        android:tag="my_tag">
 </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
```

Comment: As you can see in the [Create a fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#java:~:text=Note%3A%20You%20can%20use%20the%20class%20attribute%20instead%20of%20android%3Aname%20as%20an%20alternative%20way%20to%20specify%20which%20Fragment%20to%20instantiate.) documentation saying that it must be ``android:name`` is incorrect, since it can also be ``class``.

Answer (score 1):

For Unknown fragments error solution for Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 1 (Electric Eel):

use this:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="xxxxxx.xxxxxx.FragmentName"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_name"
/>
```

Remember, add the tools:layout...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Unknown fragments error solution for Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 1 (Electric Eel):**

Click the red icon with exclamation mark.

[image: Step 1]

In bottom panel with errors found in layout, select `Unknown fragments`.

[image: Step 2]

In right part of bottom panel, click the link `Do not warn about <android.fragment.app. FragmentContainerView> tags in this session`

[image: Step 3]

Congratulations! Your layout preview is now working again!

**NOTE:** Sadly, this solution only works until you close Android Studio. If anyone knows about permanent solution, please let me know in comments and I will update this answer.